# How to export a jpg asset from a depedency module with Vite.js?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, vite

I have a Vite React library called finalLibrary. That library has a dependency to a node module that contains grass.jpg file in node_modules/dependency_module/grass.jpg.

How can I export the grass.jpg from the dependency_module in the finalLibrary library?